# Replace a specific type with another type in a nested object typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to replace a specific type with another type, as so:

```
interface Human {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isMarried: boolean;
  animals: [
    { name: string, age: number}, 
    { name: string, age: number}
  ]
}

type HumanString = ReplaceTypes<Human, number, string>

/*
HumanString {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  isMarried: boolean;
  animals: [
    { name: string, age: string}, 
    { name: string, age: string}
  ]
}
*/
```

Where the has the following interface `ReplaceTypes<OriginalType, OldType, NewType>`
`Oldtype` should be replaced in all nested occurances for `NewType`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with a recursive mapped type that looks like this:

```typescript
type ReplaceTypes<ObjType extends object, FromType, ToType> = {
    [KeyType in keyof ObjType]: ObjType[KeyType] extends object
        ? ReplaceTypes<ObjType[KeyType], FromType, ToType>  // Recurse
        : ObjType[KeyType] extends FromType    // Not recursing, need to change?
            ? ToType                           // Yes, change it
            : ObjType[KeyType];                // No, keep original
}
```

So for instance, if you had `example: HumanString`, `example.age` and `example.animals[number].age` would both be `string` instead of `number`.

It looks to see if the type of each property extends object and if so, recurses; otherwise, it looks to see if the type extends the "from" type and replaces it if so.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIFcC2cTIN4BQyxyIcmEAXMgM5hSgDmA3ESXI1aVgEbSslkwGgFk4UBhAAm1HgHs5AGwg4B7EMGyKa1ANptBxPKXJc6DEIwA0yDlxC9oAXxsHDxshWrmmNu9QdMPignNwBdAlCCMABPAAcUACUIOMVECAAVeIgaAB4AeR4AKyyE5AgAD0gQKRpkOWKIBDAbADEoOUxSiBsMuW6APmQAXnw3XQBpCBjuoVwAa2m5GGRCkuyw6jXuyenusPKqiBq6hqKmsDdBAH5kZNT07rzt7N2ZjbaOruze-uyBq4kLbFHZTd4JA6Vaq1ZDtTrdQGGZC3PoIpFI4HrBJvfasKKxMoYbAgADK9CYIzuKTSSCeuSJOBsgWCNh8lgBBCkTTSUBQyjAh3IqS4DNJ5MsrEqQuUADo7AQAPQKpEAPWuBClmGFco0WhougADGE5ZxFcr0RbkGqCIqAFQEUVkiyMMaCTxmcUsNz+WietTEYRiCTAaSyBTKVTe3VwbR6RH4ExeX3OvycbyelzIeMeUzplO2NPJpihQQRUK2hVAA)

All of those repeated instances of `ObjType[KeyType]` get tiresome, so you could split it up into two parts:

```typescript
type ReplaceType<Type, FromType, ToType> =
    Type extends object
    ? ReplaceTypes<Type, FromType, ToType>
    : Type extends FromType
        ? ToType
        : Type;

type ReplaceTypes<ObjType extends object, FromType, ToType> = {
    [KeyType in keyof ObjType]: ReplaceType<ObjType[KeyType], FromType, ToType>;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JxvJGXMh8-hCxGS7Yy8WmKFBBFQj69UA)

**If** you wanted to be able to do this with `FromType` being an object, type, it should work if you change the order:

```typescript
type ReplaceType<Type, FromType, ToType> =
    Type extends FromType                       // FromType?
    ? ToType                                    // Yes, replace it
    : Type extends object                       // Recurse?
        ? ReplaceTypes<Type, FromType, ToType>  // Yes
        : Type;                                 // No, leave it alone

type ReplaceTypes<ObjType extends object, FromType, ToType> = {
    [KeyType in keyof ObjType]: ReplaceType<ObjType[KeyType], FromType, ToType>;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsIGNgBVzQC8UA3gB4BcUAdgK4KoQBOA3AL4sBQnAltcMwBmAQyzQAEvWHVSnKPJrCkVAM7AmfAOZcFUYZohV4SNJhz5IOhTxUBZYUw0QAJlVRw4AGwjSr86TwIwp4qVADacroKJIrKUGoa1JoANHoGRogoGNh4BGypkVGksYbx6lqp+qXGWWa5kGyFUAC6nI2coJBQAEoQYJ6iEBYQADzDqQBiTIjjULhwwwB8UIRNw1AQZALUzipQUzMETQD8cwtHulTrm9u7UHDZOE26p739g8MqYwST0wiz8yWzwUVwIXA6BB6fQGYk+I1M1y2EB2ewedV+h0gqUBBGWxBITTCAGkICB1nwoABrUlwQRQBEEZpUN4woYEeEYYbE0nDZoY-4-M5LLjtToSKTUGDlJIrKHvWEEL6SILUVI1Uw5WYJLSLbjObADJjQbzADZkJT9UrK6RSxLaTibC3eAB0VU4AHp3UUAHrHB3mhCW13UQLBFRhAAMzVdBg9XqKCYUvs4QA)