# Inferring the result type based on (optional) properties using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Afterwards I am showing a detailed example of my actual problem. The following code shows a simplified problem:

```
type Mapper<T, R> = (data: T) => R;

interface Config<T, R> {
  readonly mapper?: Mapper<T, R>;
}

function transform<T, R>(config: Config<T, R>, data: T) {
  return config.mapper?.(data) ?? data;
}


const mapper: Mapper<number, string> = (data: number) => `${data};`
const result1 = transform({}, 1); // I expect result1 to be of type number as no mapper is given.
const result2 = transform({ mapper }, 1); // I expect result2 to be of type string as a mapper is given.
```

How to type the result of `transform` properly. Note, that the function `transform` does not make sense. It is just a minimal example to get the gist of the actual problem explained afterwards.

---

Let's assume having the following code given:

```
export type PendingState = {
  type: "PENDING";
};

export type SuccessState<T> = {
  type: "SUCCESS";
  data: T;
};

export type ErrorState = {
  type: "ERROR";
  error: unknown;
};

export type SuspenseState<T> = PendingState | SuccessState<T> | ErrorState;

export type PendingStateMapper<R> = () => R;
export type SuccessStateMapper<T, R> = (data: T) => R;
export type ErrorStateMapper<R> = (error: unknown) => R;

export interface Mappers<T, P, S, E> {
  readonly pendingState?: PendingStateMapper<P>;
  readonly successState: SuccessStateMapper<T, S>;
  readonly errorState: ErrorStateMapper<E>;
}

export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E>(mappers: Mappers<T, P, S, E> & { pendingState: PendingStateMapper<P> }): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, P | S | E>;
export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E>(mappers: Mappers<T, P, S, E> & { pendingState?: undefined }): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, null | S | E>;
export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E>(mappers: Mappers<T, P, S, E>): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, P | S | E | null> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<P | S | E | null> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return mappers.pendingState ? mappers.pendingState() : null;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return mappers.successState(state.data);
          case "ERROR":
            return mappers.errorState(state.error);
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Currently I am using function overloading to properly infer the return type. If `PendingStateMapper` is given the *result of the mapper* is returned, hence `P`. If `PendingStateMapper` is not given `null` is returned.

Let's assume that `SuccessStateMapper` and `ErrorStateMapper` should be optional as well. If `SuccessStateMapper` is given `S` should be returned, otherwise `T` should be returned. If `ErrorStateMapper` is given `E` should be returned, otherwise `unknown` should be returned.

Using the current approach of overloading functions would required a lot of different signatures in order to cover all possible solutions.

Therefore, I am wondering if this could be solved in a different way. I had something like this in mind. Unfortunately the following code is not working though:

```
export type PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M extends { readonly pendingState: PendingStateMapper<P> } ? P : null;

export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>>(mappers: M): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M> | S | E> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M> | S | E> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return mappers.pendingState ? mappers.pendingState() : null;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return mappers.successState(state.data);
          case "ERROR":
            return mappers.errorState(state.error);
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

It compiles giving TypeScript a dedicated hint though. One line of the following code would have to be adjusted like this:

```
return (mappers.pendingState?. () ?? null) as PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
```

Unfortunately using `fromSuspenseState` does not infer the types correctly though.

Finally I came up with the following code, which seems to work.

```
type PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["pendingState"] extends PendingStateMapper<infer R> ? R : null;
type SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["successState"] extends SuccessStateMapper<T, infer R> ? R : T;
type ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["errorState"] extends ErrorStateMapper<infer R> ? R : unknown;

export type FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> =
  | PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;

export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>>(mappers: M): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return (mappers.pendingState?.() ?? null) as PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return (mappers.successState?.(state.data) ?? state.data) as SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "ERROR":
            return (mappers.errorState?.(state.error) ?? state.error) as ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

In the course of writing and updating this issue I basically found the solution myself. I am still wondering if there is a general rule of thumb how to infer the result type based on a property of a given parameter. Maybe it depends on the situation.

I appreciate anyone sharing his experience tackling such "problems".

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like [this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vidyard-player/types/vidyard/index.d.ts#L61). Depending on the event name I can require other parameters

Comment: I would like to know how to properly type the result based on a property of a given parameter. I am wondering if there is a rule of thumb or if it always depends on the situation.

Comment: You are right, I should definitely come up with a simpler example. Thanks for the feedback. Just as a note, the mentioned types are used form rxjs.

Comment: Thank you @Pieterjan, I will definitely look into this.

Comment: Definitely. I will keep this in mind for future questions. Thank you @jcalz.

Comment: It's possible you might be looking for [generic type argument defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzqA3m), but right now I still need a [mre] that we can test with. Could you please edit with some example calls to your function and what types you expect to see?

Comment: I tried to add a simplified example at the very beginning to the issue.

Comment: Did you look at the playground link? [Here's another one.](https://tsplay.dev/mxEBKW).  It uses generic type argument defaults. If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Could you solve it with the simplified example?

Comment:  I'm not sure what the disconnect is.  [This link](https://tsplay.dev/mxEBKW) has both your examples in it, both of which are "solved" to the best of my ability.  Please take your time and look at it, and tell me if I'm still missing something. I'm willing to believe that I'm off base and not understanding what you're asking for, but could you triple check to see that you're not just overlooking my suggestion somehow? Like, `result1` and `result2` are at the top of my link. Isn't that what you want them to be?

Comment: Did you actually try to implement it? I did and experienced problems. See https://tsplay.dev/wQj57N.

Comment: Generics and switch/case never play nicely together; I presumed you didn't care much about type safety in the *implementation* because you were already using overloads and type assertions in your "working" versions.  Just use one of those like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0eoaW).  This is the first you've mentioned the implementation type safety situation; may I presume that my suggestions do indeed fully address your question as asked and your question about implementation typing is out of scope? If so I'll write up my answer. If not, what continues to be missing?

Comment: I actually care about type safety. I apologise if another impression was given. Therefore, I don't want to use "any". Furthermore, I would like to define the return type explicitly in order to avoid violating linting rules. That's why the proposed solution is currently no alternative. And I don't insist on the switch statement. I just want to use the appropriate mapper based on the type of the SuspenseState. I really appreciate your effort, therefore I hope you don't feel offended by this clear statement.

Comment: You say you care about type safety but overloads and type assertions (`as`) are not type safe at all. You can easily avoid `any`, like [this](//tsplay.dev/mZ5rEN), for example, but this is no more type safe; `any` is at least obvious about it. But this is truly out of scope for your question *as asked*; if you care about the implementation being type safe then you should mention and show it in the question, not merely in a comment. But then you should not accept your conditional type solution either, since it has the same problem. I'm not offended but I am getting weary; how shall we proceed?

Comment: (see prev) Hmm, I see you apparently now have "linting rule" constraints so I think we are at an impasse. SO is not meant for one-on-one tech support; it's a resource for future readers too: a question which adds requirements as solutions are proposed isn't good for that. At this point you're not asking for a question with a correct answer, you're asking for your own personal code helper to provide a solution tailor-made to your needs instead of accepting a more general solution. At this point I can either write my suggestion as an answer or just disengage completely; which would you prefer?

Comment: Again, I really appreciate your effort, but I don't understand why you are that eager providing an answer to be accepted. In my opinion the main question is still valid: "Inferring the result type based on (optional) properties using TypeScript" with the requirement of complete type safety, hence no usage of "any" or casts. That's what I would be looking for. Maybe this is not possible. Anyway, your solution is definitely an alternative as it works as well using casts or an overload signature using "any". I was not aware of this and definitely learned something new. Thank's for this.

Comment: In my opinion two possible solutions are given, which are both not completely type safe. If complete type safety can't be reached it's probably a question of personal preference.

Comment: I’m going to disengage now and not respond to further comments here. Good luck.

Comment: I guess this stack overflow answer explains the problem regarding type safety very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964091/13513418.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there are multiple approaches to resolve the described problem.

---

**Alternative 1:**

*This alternative uses conditional types within `PendingStateMapperResult`, `SuccessStateMapperResult` and `ErrorStateMapperResult`.*

```
type PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M extends { readonly pendingState: PendingStateMapper<infer R> } ? R : null;
type SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M extends { readonly successState: SuccessStateMapper<T, infer R> } ? R : T;
type ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M extends { readonly errorState: PendingStateMapper<infer R> } ? R : unknown;

export type FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> =
  | PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;

export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E> = Mappers<T, P, S, E>>(
  mappers: M
): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return (mappers.pendingState?.() ?? null) as PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return (mappers.successState?.(state.data) ?? state.data) as SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "ERROR":
            return (mappers.errorState?.(state.error) ?? state.error) as ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

**Alternative 2:**

*This alternative is very similar to alternative 1 and uses conditional types within `PendingStateMapperResult`, `SuccessStateMapperResult` and `ErrorStateMapperResult` as well. It just uses another syntactical approach.*

```
type PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["pendingState"] extends PendingStateMapper<infer R> ? R : null;
type SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["successState"] extends SuccessStateMapper<T, infer R> ? R : T;
type ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> = M["errorState"] extends ErrorStateMapper<infer R> ? R : unknown;

export type FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E>> =
  | PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>
  | ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;

export function fromSuspenseState<T, P, S, E, M extends Mappers<T, P, S, E> = Mappers<T, P, S, E>>(
  mappers: M
): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<FromSuspenseStateResult<T, P, S, E, M>> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return (mappers.pendingState?.() ?? null) as PendingStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return (mappers.successState?.(state.data) ?? state.data) as SuccessStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
          case "ERROR":
            return (mappers.errorState?.(state.error) ?? state.error) as ErrorStateMapperResult<T, P, S, E, M>;
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

**Alternative 3:**

*This alternative is mainly inspired by the discussion in the comments with "jcalz". It uses [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).*

```
export function fromSuspenseState<T, P = null, S = T, E = unknown>(mappers: Mappers<T, P, S, E>): OperatorFunction<SuspenseState<T>, P | S | E> {
  return (source$: Observable<SuspenseState<T>>): Observable<P | S | E> => {
    return source$.pipe(
      map((state) => {
        switch (state.type) {
          case "PENDING":
            return (mappers.pendingState?.() ?? null) as P;
          case "SUCCESS":
            return (mappers.successState?.(state.data) ?? state.data) as S;
          case "ERROR":
            return (mappers.errorState?.(state.error) ?? state.error) as E;
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

---

Unfortunately, each alternative has to use a type cast. It seems that this is currently necessary due to [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76961092/how-to-type-a-generic-function-with-conditional-return-type-without-casting).

I guess [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) signatures could be used to prevent the type cast, but this could lead to excessive function overloading as many variants would have to be covered.